# Disabling TLS 1.0 prevents Client HELLO packet

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012

We have an application that we are trying to get to communicate to Paypal.  We noticed that communication failures were occurring, so we routed everything through Charles as a proxy.  When we routed the application through Charles, the application worked.  I investigated the network traffic and it appears that Charles will initiate the SSL communication channel over TLS 1.2.

[image]

When Charles was not being the proxy, the application tries to use TLS 1.0 and it fails at the Client Hello message.

I decided to disable TLS 1.0 on the server by disabling it in IE and changing the TLS 1.0 registry keys DisabledByDefault = 0 and Enabled = 0.  When I do this and reboot the server and run the application, I see communication to the Paypal servers, but no client handshake and the application fails.

[image]

So I'm at a loss as to why the Client Hello message would be sent with TLS 1.0 and the TLS 1.1 and 1.2 won't send the hello message.  I've tried both '1' and 'ffffffff' as the Enabled key and neither seem to work.  Any trick to disabling 1.0 and getting 1.1 / 1.2 working?

Comment: Ask the software vendor/dev ? Seem a bug in their app, and without the app name we cant do nothing

Comment: It's Dynamics NAV, which is why I'm a bit perplexed.  I'm a .net programmer, and can't recall a way to force which version of SSL to use.  I always thought it was a system setting and not something code could control.

Comment: Applications can use different SSL libraries and support different protocol versions and cipher suites. Worth noting that www.paypal.com [does accept TLS 1.0](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?viaform=on&d=www.paypal.com) so I wonder if the application is using some weird ciphers which the Paypal servers don't like.

Comment: Hi, i know this is old topic, but I started to face similar issues, with similar tool - SharePoint is also not able to send Client Hello for TLS 1.0 while requests from PowerShell - sends correct traffic. So if you solved your problem - could you share the solution as it might point me to right direction.